# How does Drupal assembles a page

Tags: drupal, internals

Is there some architectural guide, that shows in details the various subsystems that are involved in the creation of a single page?

I've tried to find something but even the presentations at DrupalCons don't go into detail.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.freshblurbs.com/drupal-bootstrap-request-processing-drupal

Details the bootstrap process.

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but it's for Drupal 5 and doesn't explain much. I mean, I can get the same info from my debugger :)

Answer (score 0):

Page generation in Drupal involves PHPTemplate. You can have more information through [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/group/themeable/6). You can look at the function calls of each partial theme from the [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/6).